# Calculate days excluding weekends in Sharepoint2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

How do I exclude weekends(sat and sun) when counting number of days between a start and end time in Sharepoint 2010 calculate column.

1.I have a calendar added to Sharepoint 2010 and there is two columns as start time and end time and now my requirement is to calculate the number of days between star time and end time excluding the weekends(sat and sun) means it will calculate working days only.
tried this

```
=IF(AND((WEEKDAY(EndDate,2))<(WEEKDAY(StartDate,2)),((WEEKDAY(StartDate,2))-(WEEKDAY(EndDate,2)))>1),(((DATEDIF(StartDate,EndDate,"D")+1))-(FLOOR((DATEDIF(StartDate,EndDate,"D")+1)/7,1)*2)-2),(((DATEDIF(StartDate,EndDate,"D")+1))-(FLOOR((DATEDIF(StartDate,EndDate,"D")+1)/7,1)*2)))
```

Also,

```
=(DATEDIF([StartDate],[EndDate],"d"))-INT(DATEDIF([StartDate],[EndDate],"d")/7)*2-IF((WEEKDAY([EndDate])-WEEKDAY([StartDate]))>0,2,0)+1
```

but not getting the correct output.

Answer (score 2):

```
=IF(AND((WEEKDAY(EndDate,2))<(WEEKDAY(StartDate,2)),((WEEKDAY(StartDate,2))-(WEEKDAY(EndDate,2)))>1),(((DATEDIF(StartDate,EndDate,"D")+1))-(FLOOR((DATEDIF(StartDate,EndDate,"D")+1)/7,1)*2)-2),(((DATEDIF(StartDate,EndDate,"D")+1))-(FLOOR((DATEDIF(StartDate,EndDate,"D")+1)/7,1)*2)))
```

this should do the trick :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why, but I ended with above -1, that is:

```
=IF(AND((WEEKDAY(EndDate,2))<(WEEKDAY(StartDate,2)),((WEEKDAY(StartDate,2))-(WEEKDAY(EndDate,2)))>1),(((DATEDIF(StartDate,EndDate,"D")+1))-(FLOOR((DATEDIF(StartDate,EndDate,"D")+1)/7,1)*2)-2),(((DATEDIF(StartDate,EndDate,"D")+1))-(FLOOR((DATEDIF(StartDate,EndDate,"D")+1)/7,1)*2)))-1
```

Using this way it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula:

```
=DATEDIF([Start Date],[End Date],"D")-IF(WEEKDAY([End Date])=7,FLOOR((DATEDIF([Start Date],[End Date],"D")+WEEKDAY([Start Date]))/7,1)*2,FLOOR((DATEDIF([Start Date],[End Date],"D")+WEEKDAY([Start Date]))/7,1)*2+1)+IF(WEEKDAY([Start Date])=7,2,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked best for me.

```
ROUNDUP(([End Time]-[Start Time]),0)-IF(WEEKDAY([End Time])=7,FLOOR((DATEDIF([Start Time],[End Time],"D")+WEEKDAY([Start Time]))/7,1)*2,FLOOR((DATEDIF([Start Time],[End Time],"D")+WEEKDAY([Start Time]))/7,1)*2+1)+IF(WEEKDAY([Start Time])=7,2,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Formula to calculate networkdays in sp Tested and working:

```
=(DATEDIF([Start Date],[End Date],"D"))-INT(DATEDIF([Start Date],[End Date],"D")/7)*2-
IF(WEEKDAY([End Date])<WEEKDAY([Start Date]),2,
IF(OR(WEEKDAY([End Date])=7,WEEKDAY([Start Date])=1),1,0))+1
```